# Angular2 CLI build destination based on Environment

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a way to tell angular2 cli to build to a certain path based on which build you are running?

1. I want angular cli to build to "distDev" folder if i run a normal "ng build".
2. I want angular cli to build to "distProd" folder if i run a "ng build --prod".

I have tried adding outDir: "distDev" to my environment.ts file without any luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/build.md?

Comment: I did @jonrsharpe. The article you linked gives me the option to specify the target when i write the build command such as "ng build --target=production --environment=prod", but i want to specify the dist folders in the environment.ts file..

Comment: 1. That's not the `--target`, the option for the output path is, err, `--output-path`. 2. It doesn't make sense for that to be in the environment, which is for information the app needs; the app doesn't care what you named the directory. As far as I can tell it's not an option.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - you missed the "point" of the question, and maybe because Hazar didn't have all the information - I believe he meant to ask IN THE Angular-cli.json doc ..not in the environment templates...He wants to (and I see VERY valid reasons) to have his build output one place for each environment...as do I. without having to explicitly type it every time.

Comment: @jpmyob depending on the CLI version you're using you can now probably do that via the `projects[yourProject].architect.build` settings, look at `options.outputPath` and the `configurations` overrides. Or just add package scripts and set up e.g. `[npm run/yarn] build` and `[...] build:prod` so you don't need to type the flags every time.